# discord.py ban users outisde of guild

Tags: discord, discord.py

When I try to use the command it says "user is a required argument"

```py
@commands.command(aliases=['hban'])
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
@commands.cooldown(1, 3, BucketType.user)
async def hackban(self, ctx, user: discord.User):
    if user in ctx.guild.members:
        embed = discord.Embed(description=":oxmark:  "+f"Unsuccessful, the user is in this guild. [-help ban]", color=discord.Color.orange())
        await ctx.reply(embed=embed, mention_author=False)

    else:
        await ctx.guild.ban(user)
        embed = discord.Embed(title=":ocheckmark:  "+f"Successfully hack banned {user.name}", color=discord.Color.orange())
        await ctx.reply(embed=embed, mention_author=False)
```

Comment: i got it but thanks bru

Answer (score -1):

```py
@client.command()
@check(check_if_user_has_premium)
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def hackban(ctx, user: discord.User = None):
    guild = ctx.guild
    if user == None:
        await ctx.send("Please enter a member to ban") 
        return()
    else:
        await guild.ban(user)
        embed = discord.Embed(title=":ocheckmark:  "+f"Successfully hack banned {user.name}", color=discord.Color.orange())
        await ctx.reply(embed=embed, mention_author=False)
```

Works

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).